# Get a dynamic element to change text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic element in my web page like this that appear when I click on an icon:

```
<span class="elasticbar-item text-right text-baseline">
      <button class="button primary" data-next-button="">MY TEXT</button>
</span>
```

But I want to change default text that come from server (where I don't have access) with a new text.

What I tried before now is represented by:

```
var buttonIntervalCheck = setInterval(function () {
  var button = $("[data-next-button]");

  if(button.length === 1) {
    button.text("NEW TEXT");
    clearInterval(buttonIntervalCheck);
  }
}, 1000);
```

Example in Google Chrome

[image]

First result is when I clicked on my icon.
Second result is when I make Inspect on the button (Ctrl+Shift+I) on the button.

And I don't understand how exactly works.
How I can fix it?

Comment: The element isn't found? Do you mean the `button.length` is always 0?

Comment: Yes, is always 0.

Comment: So what do you expect when it is 0 @Adrian

Comment: Can you come up with a [MCVE]?

Comment: In Chrome, in console, the element exist, but just when I make inspect on element from page.

Comment: I added a print from Chrome console.

Answer (score 1):

Try running this on your console:

```
$("[data-next-button]").text("NEW TEXT");
```

If it works correctly, then your timing is wrong. You are probably calling `button.text` before the DOM has loaded. Try wrapping your code around the ready fuction:

```
$(function() {
  var buttonIntervalCheck = setInterval(function () {
  var button = $("[data-next-button]");

  if(button.length === 1) {
    button.text("NEW TEXT");
    clearInterval(buttonIntervalCheck);
  }
}, 1000);
});
```

Comment: My part of code is in `$(document).ready(function() { ... }`. Doesn't work before I make an inspect.

Comment: maybe it's in an iframe?

Comment: Yes, it's an iframe. So, I can't change, no? :(

Comment: Look up "change contents of iframe" here in stackoverflow, I believe it's not possible (at least in a non-hacky way).

Answer (score 0):

You can't select a dynamic element with jquery , try with js like

```
document.querySelector("[data-next-button]")
```

Comment: `You can't select a dynamic element with jquery` why?

Comment: It's same, the element is visible just after a make an inspect on the element.

Comment: because when jquery is loaded it gives an ID to each element so coming elements haven't ID

Answer (score 0):

In the example below there is a `setTimeout()` that adds the `button` in the HTML dynamically in 5 seconds. Then, the `setInterval()`  changes the text of the `button` and close the interval. Everything worked as you expected. I don't see any error here.

```js
var buttonIntervalCheck = setInterval(function () {
  var button = $("[data-next-button]");

  if(button.length === 1) {
    button.text("NEW TEXT");
    clearInterval(buttonIntervalCheck);
  }
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function(){
  $('#ss').html(`<span class="elasticbar-item text-right text-baseline">
      <button class="button primary" data-next-button="">MY TEXT</button>
</span>`);
}, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='ss'></div>
```

Comment: Code comes from server, I can't add a div in page and change the content. I want to change the text after the code is inserted in page.